# Fullscreen mode in Windows 10 default photo viewer

Tags: windows-10

Is there any way to enable fullscreen mode in Windows 10 default photo viewer? I know there is a slideshow option but I don't want a slideshow, I want to manually change images.

Comment: Click the "maximize" button.?

Comment: Maximize button leaves the title bar and task bar visible so it's not fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

Press Windows Key + Shift + Enter together to switch to fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10,

1. Open 'Microsoft Photos' app
2. Right click on a photo
3. Select 'Change small media settings'
4. Select 'Always zoom to fit'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).